# Is change in enthalpy heat supplied at constant internal or external pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

From what I understood, we introduced enthalpy to work with reactions that were carried out at constant external pressure. But then I came across this formula (for ideal gas):
∆H=∆U + p∆V
where  p∆V=∆n(RT).
But doesn't the p in the second formula represent the external pressure? So how are we using pv=nRT which is only valid if the pressure we are dealing with is the internal pressure of the gas?

Comment: By Newton's 3rd law, the force per unit area exerted by a gas on its surroundings is equal in magnitude to the pressure the surroundings exerts on the gas. In this sense, the "internal pressure" is always equal to the external pressure.  In an irreversible process, however, the" internal pressure" is not determined by the ideal gas law (or other real gas equation of state).  Did you think it was?

Comment: Yes, I did..so how is it determined?

Comment: The ideal gas law is valid only for thermodynamic equilibrium states.  In rapid irreversible deformations, viscous stresses also contribute to the compressive stresses in a gas.  So, unless the stress on the gas is specified based on external considerations, say specified external pressure, the compressive stress in the gas at the piston face must be solved for using the complicated partial differential equations of fluid dynamics combined with the partial differential energy equation within the gas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the change occurs irreversibly for the ideal gas mixture, the work is still $\int{P_{ext}dV}$.  The equation you wrote assumes that the initial and final states of the gas are thermodynamic equilibrium states at pressure p, and that the external pressure is also $P_{ext}=p$ over the entire change.  In that case, the work done by the gas on its surroundings, even if the change occurs irreversibly, is $W=P_{ext}\Delta V=p\Delta V$.

Answer (score -1):

When a work $p$∆$V$ occurs in thermodynamic calculations, whatever the ± sign of the work, the pressure $p$ is the pressure of the force doing the work. When a work $w$ is done on a sample of gas whose volume decreases, the pressure $p$ to introduce in the work formula is the outer pressure $p_{ext}$ . On the contrary, when the work $w$ is done for example by the heated inner gas so that its volume increases by ∆$V$, in this case the force doing the work comes from the inner gas, and the working pressure is the inner pressure $p_{int}$.

Summary : Whatever the ± sign of the work,

1. when the work $w$ is positive (when the volume is decreasing), the pressure $p$ included in $p$∆$V$ is the inner pressure  $p_{int}$
2. when the work $w$ is negative (when the volume is increasing), the pressure $p$ included in $p$∆$V$ is the outer pressure $p_{ext}$

Comment: But in all the books that I have come  across, it was always specifically mentioned that in ∆u=q+w, work done is always take as -∫(p external )dv

Comment: Yes. Work done on the system is always obtained using the external pressure